# Update CodenameOne sidemenu command when a property value changes

Tags: codenameone

I want to be able to change the title of my Side menu command based on the size of a ListProperty which is dynamically updated. I have tried to do this via a changeListener, but i can not get this to work.

```
Command cmdWishlist = tb.addMaterialCommandToRightSideMenu("Wishlist(" + Shop.getInstance().wishList.size() + ")", FontImage.MATERIAL_FAVORITE, e -> {
        ....
    });
    Shop.getInstance().wishList.addChangeListener(pl -> {
        tb.revalidate();
    });
```

If however, I open another form, and check the sidemenu, the change that I need is reflecting. How can I get this to work? By the way, I get the desired behavior if i put, say a label on the toolbar and `setText("Wishlist(" + Shop.getInstance().wishList.size() + ")` in the change listener.

Please point me in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we add a command to the side menu or a button we extract its values but don't automatically reflect updates as that can cause a potential memory leak by binding commands to components. The workaround is to modify the original underlying component too e.g.:

```
Button ui = tb.findCommandComponent(cmd);
ui.setText(newLabelForCommand);
```